# "You'd better try again.", is this sentence comparative or advice, or both?

Tags: grammar

Yesterday we had an exam and our teacher asked a question which said:

> You'd better try again.

And I picked "advice", but then the teacher said, that sentence is both advice and also comparative because there's the word "better" in it. I tried to argue but I wasn't so sure.

So the question is, is it both of them?

Comment: *You'd better try again* is not a question.

Comment: It was a question in the exam.

Comment: [English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/had-better) contains << 'Had better' is a strong expression. We use it if we think there will be negative results if someone does not do what is desired or suggested:

_She’d better get here soon or she’ll miss the opening ceremony._ >>. This obviously has at least an implied comparison (the consequences of not-A as contrasted with those of A).